# Speech Api limits to 65 seconds instead of 180 minutes

Tags: c#, google-cloud-speech

according to https://cloud.google.com/speech/quotas, asyncronous request lasts 180 minutes.

But when I use this code:

```
public async Task<object> StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(int seconds)
{
    streamingCall =  SpeechClient.Create().StreamingRecognize();
    await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
        new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
        {
            StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
            {
                Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                {
                    Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                    SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                    LanguageCode = "en-US" 
                },
                InterimResults = true,
                SingleUtterance = false
            }
        }
    );

    Task prinResp = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(default(CancellationToken)))
        {
            foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream.Current.Results)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(result.Alternatives[0].Transcript.ToString());
            }
        }
    });

    // Read from the microphone and stream to API.
    object writeLock = new object();
    bool writeMore = true;
    waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent();
    waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
    waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(16000, 1);
    waveIn.DataAvailable +=
        (object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs args) =>
        {
            lock (writeLock)
            {
                if (!writeMore || !isActive) return;
                try
                {
                    streamingCall.WriteAsync(
                        new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                        {
                            AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(args.Buffer, 0, args.BytesRecorded)
                        }).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { my.message(e.Message); }
            }
        };

    waveIn.StartRecording();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180*60));
    waveIn.StopRecording();
    lock (writeLock) writeMore = false;
    await streamingCall.WriteCompleteAsync();
    await prinResp; 
    return 0;
}
```

after 65 seconds `streamingCall.WriteAsync` shows "Exceeded maximum allowed stream duration of 65 seconds." error.

How do i Get 180 minutes?
( i.e. on translate.google.com you can use "speak" feature more than minute, how can achieve it)?

Comment: I never used this API, but the docs says "Audio longer than ~1 minute must use the uri field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage.", and I don't see this in your code

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks, nice catch. you could post it as answer. btw, but how `translate.google.com` does that for longer than 1min?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CamiloTerevinto mentioned, you will need to provide a Cloud Storage URI for your Speech API's Asynchronous request to last more than 1 minute. Translate.google.com is a Google tool and those not have the same limitations as a public API. I also believe the translate tool stream the audio, uploads it to a temporary cloud storage, uses speech API to convert to text so it can be translated.

You can upload the stream to Google Cloud Storage using [Google.Cloud.Storage.V1](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/) API. The return URI can then be used with the Speech API Asynchronous request and should process up to 180 min of audio.

Google has a couple of small [examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api) on how to use the Speech API with different scenarios, including with the Google Storage URI. I would suggest looking into it.

Hope it helps